# How to target debug flash player in Flash Builder 4 on Mac OS X

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I'm pulling my hair out with this one.

How do I set which Flash Player to use when running a project?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same mechanism as under windows, Flash Builder will use the last flash player you launched.

EDIT : To ensure that Flash Builder launches your project in a SA player you need to uncheck "generate HTML" in the "Flex Compiler" tab of the project properties windows

Comment: Yeah, but it opens in a browser. I want to use a standalone Flash debugger player. In fact, how do I install the standalone player in the first place? I've downloaded the one from here[1], but where does it go into? [1]http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: If it is ok that it opens in the browser, if it is a web project, you can use the debug version of the plugin by simply replacing the Flash Player.plugin in the "Internet Plug-Ins" folder with the debug version that you can download from that URL.

Answer (score 0):

It goes in Applications/Flash Builder/player/11.9/Flash Player Debugger.app 
And in Flash Builder you go to preferences -> Flash Builder -> Debug and browse for that file